# AWS EC2 Windows server 2016 PPTP VPN not connecting because of GRE not allowed?

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2016, pptp, gre

I have an EC2 instance of windows server 2016. I want to setup a PPTP VPN on it so I can access services and stuff in the domain controller.

I already setup the PPTP in the windows server, but I'm getting this error when I try to connect to the VPN using my windows 11 PC, it gets [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5rx5.png).

Now, I already setup on the inbound rule on the AWS for the instance to accept [port 47 and 1723 for the GRE and PPTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRjyn.png). But the error still persist.

It says there that it could be because of the firewall or router. I already allowed TCP ports 47 and 1723 on the windows 11 firewall. And for my ISP, I am just using a regular home connection and I also tried express VPN using the same connection and it was working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRE is not TCP port 47<sup>1</sup> – it's **IP protocol 47**, being on the same level as the TCP (6) and UDP (17) protocols. Your rules should look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the EC2 security group rules]

PPTP is not a good choice for a VPN – its default authentication method (MSCHAPv2) is about as good as sending a whole password in the clear, and the MPPE encryption is extremely weak as well. Adding that to the GRE-related issues you'll encounter when connecting from behind various NATs, you should *really* consider a different VPN protocol. (IKEv2 is a secure option that Windows supports, but WireGuard would be much simpler to set up.)

(Still, it's better than outright exposing RDP to the world.)

---

<sup>1</sup> (and especially not *TCP* port 47 – GRE is a datagram-based tunnel similar to UDP, so if it were layered on top of the "standard" protocols then it would have a UDP port instead.)

Comment: hi, now it works, thank you very much... also thank you for the info, i will definitely check out the other vpn protocols, i wouldn't have known that GRE is bad if you haven't informed me, i was just checking around for any solution for my personal network